# How to determine if URL exists using Sharepoint API?

Tags: vb.net, api, sharepoint

How can I determine if my current full URL is existing?

Basically, I am doing a checking on all pages in a given site. The output of all pages is in XML. However, what if I deleted a page, I want to know if the URL is still existing or NOT so I can update the output.

Example:
Here is my url:

http://mySite.com/Pages/Page1.aspx

Given this URL, how can I determine if it still exists?
I tried to use SPWeb.OpenWeb but SpWeb.Exists always return a True value.

Comment: Please checkout the similar post [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020177/how-best-to-determine-if-a-given-url-represents-an-actual-sharepoint-web-site

Comment: The page linked to by sharmila has been removed by Stackoverflow moderators.